# pull all elements with specific name from a nested list

Tags: r, purrr

I have some archived Slack data that I am trying to get some of key message properties. I'd done this by stupidly flattening the entire list, getting a data.frame or tibble with lists nested in some cells. As this dataset gets bigger, I want to pick elements out of this list more smartly so that when this cache becomes big it doesn't take forever to create the data.frame or tibble with the elements I want.

Example where I am trying to pull everything named "type" below into a vector or flat list that I can pull in as a dataframe variable. I named the folder and message level for convenience. Anyone have model code that can help?

```
library(tidyverse)
    
l <- list(folder_1 = list(
  `msg_1-1` = list(type = "message",
               subtype = "channel_join",
               ts = "1585771048.000200",
               user = "UFUNNF8MA",
               text = "<@UFUNNF8MA> has joined the channel"),
  `msg_1-2` = list(type = "message",
                   subtype = "channel_purpose",
                   ts = "1585771049.000300",
                   user = "UNFUNQ8MA",
                   text = "<@UNFUNQ8MA> set the channel purpose: Talk about xyz")),
  folder_2 = list(
    `msg_2-1` = list(type = "message",
                  subtype = "channel_join",
                  ts = "1585771120.000200",
                  user = "UQKUNF8MA",
                  text = "<@UQKUNF8MA> has joined the channel")) 
)

# gets a specific element
print(l[[1]][[1]][["type"]])

# tried to get all elements named "type", but am not at the right list level to do so
print(purrr::map(l, "type"))
```

Comment: Try with `lapply(l,function(x) x[[1]][["type"]])`

Comment: Thanks! That returns the `type` for `msg_1-1` and `msg_2-1`, but not for `msg_2-1`.  Is there an apply() family or purrr call that will get all three (1-1, 1-2, 2-1)?

Comment: Here's two possible approaches:
A). if every message is at the same depth just `purrr::flatten(l) %>% purrr::keep(~identical(.x$type, "message))` B) if messages are at varying depths check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082797/how-would-i-write-a-recursive-version-of-purrrkeep

Comment: Also try `unlist(l)[grepl('.type',names(unlist(l)),fixed=T)]`

Comment: another alternative is `purrr::map(l, ~ purrr::map(.x, "type"))`

Comment: @Duck your `unlist(l)...` suggestion provides something close to what I was trying to produce. The named vector is nice for debugging too, thanks!

Comment: @M.Wood Fantastic! Would you agree on posting it as solution?

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk That's EXACTLY what I was looking for... did not think to nest a `map()` call as a mapper function inside `map()` !

Comment: @Duck sure! looks like I have 2 options here, should provide both for others depending on their base R v. tidyverse preference. Will do that soon. Thanks again!

Comment: @bcarlsen thanks for that suggestion, your solution is a nice filter for the last list given that an element in it meets a criteria, I was looking for something that returned the values in one of those bottom list elements. I think combining with something like AbdessabourMtk or Duck's solution should help me to gracefully pull all the elements I'd like. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to those provided by @Duck & @Abdessabour Mtk yesterday, purrr has a function `map_depth()` that will let you get a named attribute if you know its name and how deep it is in the hierarchy. REALLY useful when crawling this big nested lists, and is a simpler solution to the nested `map()` calls above.

```
purrr::map_depth(l, 2, "type")
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the desired output, I would probably use a simple recursive function here.

```r
get_elements <- function(x, element) {
  if(is.list(x))
  {
    if(element %in% names(x)) x[[element]]
    else lapply(x, get_elements, element = element)
  }
}
```

This allows:

```r
get_elements(l, "type")
#> $folder_1
#> $folder_1$`msg_1-1`
#> [1] "message"
#> 
#> $folder_1$`msg_1-2`
#> [1] "message"
#> 
#> 
#> $folder_2
#> $folder_2$`msg_2-1`
#> [1] "message"
```

Or if you want to get all "users":

```r
get_elements(l, "user")
#> $folder_1
#> $folder_1$`msg_1-1`
#> [1] "UFUNNF8MA"
#> 
#> $folder_1$`msg_1-2`
#> [1] "UNFUNQ8MA"
#> 
#> 
#> $folder_2
#> $folder_2$`msg_2-1`
#> [1] "UQKUNF8MA"
```

You could obviously unlist the result if you prefer it flattened into a vector.

```r
unlist(get_elements(l, "type"))
#> folder_1.msg_1-1 folder_1.msg_1-2 folder_2.msg_2-1 
#>        "message"        "message"        "message"
```

Comment: you need to change the `lapply` function argument from `get_type` to `get_elements`

Answer (score 2):

As OP mentioned, this can solve the issue:

```
#Code
unlist(l)[grepl('.type',names(unlist(l)),fixed=T)]
```

Output:

```
folder_1.msg_1-1.type folder_1.msg_1-2.type folder_2.msg_2-1.type 
            "message"             "message"             "message"
```

Another options are (Many thanks and credit to **@Abdessabour Mtk**)

```
#Code1
purrr::map(l, ~ purrr::map(.x, "type"))
```

Comment: @AbdessabourMkt , if I were ty try to access a level below type (were it to exist), how would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package:

```r
library(rrapply)

## return unlisted vector
rrapply(l, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "type", how = "unlist")
#> folder_1.msg_1-1.type folder_1.msg_1-2.type folder_2.msg_2-1.type 
#>             "message"             "message"             "message"

## return melted data.frame
rrapply(l, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "type", how = "melt")
#>         L1      L2   L3   value
#> 1 folder_1 msg_1-1 type message
#> 2 folder_1 msg_1-2 type message
#> 3 folder_2 msg_2-1 type message
```