# Accessing the elements of a list in R with something similar to xpath

Tags: r, xml, list

I have the following list in R, called `l` (in the example I create it from XML, but my real example came from a different source):

```
library(xml2)
x <- read_xml("
  <foo> 
    <bar> <baz>apple</baz> <faz>cat</faz> </bar> 
    <bar> <baz>orange</baz> <faz>dog</faz> </bar> 
  </foo>")
l <- as_list(x)

l
$foo
$foo$bar
$foo$bar$baz
$foo$bar$baz[[1]]
[1] "apple"

$foo$bar$faz
$foo$bar$faz[[1]]
[1] "cat"


$foo$bar
$foo$bar$baz
$foo$bar$baz[[1]]
[1] "orange"

$foo$bar$faz
$foo$bar$faz[[1]]
[1] "dog"
```

I need to extract all the `baz` elements from this list. If I had the data in XML format, I could do this quite simply with `xml2` using:

```
x |> xml_find_all("//faz") |> xml_text()
[1] "cat" "dog"
<faz>
```

But the solutions I've seen in R generally require complicated `lapply()` combinations that make my head hurt :-)

Is there any way to access the elements of a general R list in a similar manner? I'm not wedded to the xpath syntax per se, I'd be happy to have a solution that could somehow flatten an arbitrary list into names that looked like paths like `/foo/bar/baz` that I could then search through using `grep()` or similar, say:

```
names_as_paths(l) |> str_subset("/baz") |> extract_by_path(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this recursive function, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64579266/13460602):

```r
get_elements <- function(x, element) {
  if(is.list(x))
  {
    if(element %in% names(x)) x[[element]]
    else unname(unlist(lapply(x, get_elements, element = element)))
  }
}

get_elements(l, "faz")
#[1] "cat" "dog"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, simply applying `unlist` could suffice:

```r
L <- unlist(l) 
L
#> foo.bar.baz foo.bar.faz foo.bar.baz foo.bar.faz 
#>    "apple"       "cat"    "orange"       "dog" 

L[grep("baz",names(L))]
#> foo.bar.baz foo.bar.baz
#>    "apple"    "orange"
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted solutions are much appreciated. In the end, my own conclusion was to get more proficient with `purrr` (in particular `map_*()` and `pluck()`), as well as the Rstudio object viewer.

The process consists of diving progressively into the list, and piping intermediate results to `View()` to see what I'm doing. For the example list, this started with:

```r
library(purrr)
l.xml |>
  pluck("foo") |>
  View()
```

and the end result was:

```r
library(purrr)
l.xml |>
  pluck("foo") |>
  map_chr(pluck, "baz", 1) 
#>     bar      bar 
#>  "apple" "orange"
```

Definitely not what I was looking for at the start, but it is reasonably readable, and flexible enough to solve the tasks that originally motivated this question.